# Prevent role-specific users from accessing route

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, routes, laravel-authorization

I have 2 roles, which is `admin` and `user`. Now when logging in, the admin goes to the `dashboard` route while the user goes to `home`. When user is logged in and changes the url to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard` it can access the admin's panel and I don't want that. How can I do achieve this?

PS. I'm new to Laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good practice for this is usage of Middewares.
Create middlewares for admins and users (I'll do that only for admins, you can do that similarly for users):

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AdminMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Auth::check()){
            // check auth user role (I don't know how you can implement this for yourself, this is just for me)
            if(Auth::user()->role->name == 'admin'){
                return $next($request);
            } else {
                return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard'); // for admins
            }
        }

        return redirect()->route('main'); // for users
    }
}
```

In "app/Http/Kernel.php" in $routeMiddleware array register that (add to end of that array).

```
'Admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware::class,
```

Now if you are using all requests in "routes/web.php" (actually I think it does), then you can use routes like this for admins:

```
// USER ROUTES
Route::get('/', 'FrontController@main')->name('main');

// ADMIN ROUTES
Route::group([
    'as' => 'admin.',
    'middleware' => [ 'Admin' ],
], function () {
    Route::get('dashboard', 'AdminController@dashboard');
});
```

Refresh caches via "php artisan config:cache".
Try it!

Comment: what is the use of `Auth::check()`?

Comment: Okay I got it working now, will try to test tomorrow if everything is doing okay. Glad to have it working on first try! Thanks a lot! Will surely keep this in mind!

Answer (score 0):

Use middleware to admin route or inside the controller
like this:

```
Route::put('post/{id}', function ($id) {
//
})->middleware('role:editor');
```

or

```
Route::middleware(['auth', 'admin'])->group(function (){

Route::get('dashboard', 'HomeController@index')->name('home.index');

});
```

or inside the controller like this:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware(['auth', 'admin'])->except(['index']);
}
```

or you can use [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/middleware#middleware-parameters) for middleware roles.